# Hide custom windows title util it is completely constructed

Tags: android

I am using custom window title, and while my application loads I see how title layout is constructing (title layout is very complicated).
What I should do to hide layout construction process, and show it only when it completely constructed?
Maybe I should add some kind of white splash screen? I suggest there is simpler way...

Here is my code:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
```

Last routine takes long time. But it cannot be done util setContentView..

Comment: Can you post R.layout.title? It really shouldn't be taking so long to load one layout file... Also splash screen is definitely not the answer, it will just look strange

Comment: Also, use Traceview to figure out where your time is really being spent.

Comment: It has many gradients, pictures and so on. I am trying now to set it "invisible" in xml, and then after all set "visible", but layout construction still visible..

Comment: I also tried "gone", nothing helps. This is because window title has background, 
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">57dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>

Comment: Maybe there is the way to hide windowtitle in xml, and then show it from java code?

Comment: Can you add what is in your CustomWindowTitleBakcground?  Is it just a layout or is there more?

Comment: Background is simply gradient, nothing more

Comment: <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:angle="90"
                    android:startColor="#00ff00"
                    android:endColor="#ff0000"
                    android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>